# How to use switch statement inside a macro in C?

Tags: c, switch-statement, c-preprocessor

I want to use switch statement inside a macro in C. I have the following code segment:

```
enum errors {
    ERROR_NO_MEMORY,
    ERROR_INVALID_INDEX,
    ERROR_INVALID_VALUE
};

#define MSG_NO_MEMORY       "could not allocate memory"
#define MSG_INVALID_INDEX   "index out of bounds"
#define MSG_INVALID_VALUE   "invalid value passed as input"

#define MESSAGE(err)                    \
    switch (err) {                      \
        case ERROR_NO_MEMORY:           \
            return MSG_NO_MEMORY;       \
        case ERROR_INVALID_INDEX:       \
            return MSG_INVALID_INDEX;   \
        case ERROR_INVALID_VALUE:       \
            return MSG_INVALID_VALUE;   \
    }                                   \

#define THROW_ERROR(err)                                                        \
    fprintf(stderr, "Error in %s:%d: %s.\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, MESSAGE(err)); \
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);       \
```

But, this throws an error message, more specificially:

> error: expected expression before ‘switch’

Why is this happening exactly, and what is the proper way to use switch inside a macro in C?

Comment: How do you use this macro?

Comment: @tkausl Please check the edited question.

Comment: macro ends with `\\`: not good

Comment: You can't use macros the same way you'd use a function. Use a function instead.

Comment: You can't have a switch statement as an argument to a function.

Comment: Never use a macro if a function can do the job. There is no reason to use a macro here. That's clearly an XY problem.

Comment: To echo what others are saying in different words: preprocessor macros are the devil and should be avoided unless they provide a significant advantage to the rest of your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot `return` from a macro and expect that it behaves like a function. The macro code is expanded literally in your code, so now you have a switch/case & a bunch of `return` statements in the last parameter of `printf`!

Besides, there's no advantage to use a macro here since you're not using token pasting, stringing or other macros like `__FILE__` or `__LINE__` in it (as opposed to your `THROW_ERROR` macro which uses them).

Instead, define a `MESSAGE` (or better: `message`) function:

```
const char *message(int code)
{
       switch (err) {                      
        case ERROR_NO_MEMORY:           
           return MSG_NO_MEMORY;       
        case ERROR_INVALID_INDEX:       
          return MSG_INVALID_INDEX;   
        case ERROR_INVALID_VALUE:       
          return MSG_INVALID_VALUE;   
     }            
    return "unknown error";  // just in case no code matches
}
```

and pass that to `printf`

As an aside, wrap your `THROW_ERROR` macro within braces since there are 2 statements:

```
#define THROW_ERROR(err)  do { \
    fprintf(stderr, "Error in %s:%d: %s.\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, message(err)); \
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while(0)
```

else if you do:

```
if (fail_code) THROW_ERROR(12);
```

then only the `fprintf` statement is executed when an error occurs, and `exit` happens no matter what!

Answer (score 4):

With the expression statement extension (implemented on gcc, clang, and tinycc), you can do:

```
#define MESSAGE(err) \
    ({ int MESSAGE; switch(err){ \
         case ERROR_NO_MEMORY:           \
                MESSAGE = MSG_NO_MEMORY;       \
            case ERROR_INVALID_INDEX:       \
                MESSAGE = MSG_INVALID_INDEX;   \
            case ERROR_INVALID_VALUE:       \
                MESSAGE = MSG_INVALID_VALUE;   \
         }; MESSAGE; })
```

naturally, this isn't "portable" standard C. Portably you could use either an inline function (pretty much unchanged)
or a macro with nested ternary expressions:

```
#define MESSAGE(err) \
    ( err==ERROR_NO_MEMORY ? MSG_NO_MEMORY  \
      : err==ERROR_INVALID_INDEX ? MSG_INVALID_INDEX \
      : err==ERROR_INVALID_VALUE ? MSG_INVALID_VALUE \
      : 0 )
```

Comment: Thank you, interesting approach.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand the macro in C. It is only the textual replacement.

You need to use function for it:

```
inline const char *MESSAGE(int code)
{
    switch (err) 
    {                      
        case ERROR_NO_MEMORY:           
            return MSG_NO_MEMORY;       
        case ERROR_INVALID_INDEX:       
            return MSG_INVALID_INDEX;   
        case ERROR_INVALID_VALUE:       
            return MSG_INVALID_VALUE;   
    }
    return "";
}
```

you can od course create insane ternary macro:

```
#define MESSAGE(err) (err == ERROR_NO_MEMORY ? MSG_NO_MEMORY : err == ERROR_INVALID_INDEX ? MSG_INVALID_INDEX : .... )
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit different approach, but you can take advantage of macro concatenation.

At first, you have to re-name your error strings, such as

```
// note the name is MSG + the error enum symbol
#define MSG_ERROR_NO_MEMORY       "could not allocate memory"
#define MSG_ERROR_INVALID_INDEX   "index out of bounds"
#define MSG_ERROR_INVALID_VALUE   "invalid value passed as input"
```

Then you can take advantage of [macro concatenation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html) defining the macro `MESSAGE` as

```
#define MESSAGE(code) MSG_##code
```

This macro concats 'MSG_' with the literal given as argument.
At the end, you can use directly your `THROW_ERROR`

```
#define THROW_ERROR(err) printf("Error %", MESSAGE(err));

THROW_ERROR(ERROR_NO_MEMORY);
// expanded to -> printf("Error %", "could not allocate memory")
```

So this is the complete working example.

```
enum errors {
    ERROR_NO_MEMORY,
    ERROR_INVALID_INDEX,
    ERROR_INVALID_VALUE
};

#define MSG_ERROR_NO_MEMORY       "could not allocate memory"
#define MSG_ERROR_INVALID_INDEX   "index out of bounds"
#define MSG_ERROR_INVALID_VALUE   "invalid value passed as input"

#define MESSAGE(code) MSG_##code

#define THROW_ERROR(err)                                                        \
    fprintf(stderr, "Error in %s:%d: %s.\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, MESSAGE(err)); \
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);       \

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    THROW_ERROR(ERROR_NO_MEMORY);   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution to avoid allocating the string error message.